C program outputs to stdout just fine on Linux, but won't output anything for Windows
I wrote a pair of programs to allow someone to send arbitrary binary files over a specific radio mode with a restricted character set, where each character is represented with some Huffman code. One program is an encoder, the other is a decoder.
The programs work fine on Linux. It operates exclusively over stdin and stdout. I fuzzed them using 1 GiB random files. However, when I try to compile it for Windows (using either cl.exe or x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (on WSL), the programs refuses to output anything to any output stream.
I tried removing all outputs to stderr, tried to do two putchar() calls with '\r' '\n' (thinking it was an issue with LF vs CRLF), fflush() every time I putchar(), but it still won't work. The only thing that worked was completely commenting out the main while loop in the encoder program, in which I managed to get the initial printed string FILE:.
With the loop not commented out, I won't even get the first printf() with an immediate fflush(stdout) afterwards. The program, however, will halt. Below is one of the programs, which I want to debug first.
For sanity checking, I tried to compile a simple Hello World! program that uses both printf() and putchar(), and it works fine on Windows, but my specific program does not. I'm at a loss as to where to check first.
js8file_enc.c
#include "js8file_enc.h"

// From stdin
bool fill_buffer(bool * bitbuf, size_t * buf_size, bool ** bitbuf_read_head_ptr){
    // Justify remaining buffer back to the beginning
    if(*buf_size > 0){
        memmove(bitbuf, *bitbuf_read_head_ptr, *buf_size);
    }
    // Read from stdin (indeterminate length), keep track of buffer size
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    // The max bytes here is sizeof(buf) - ceil(*buf_size/8) expressed in a roundabout way.
    // This will fill our byte buffer as much as possible for the bit buffer to be near-full in the next step.
    size_t increase = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf) - ((*buf_size+8-1)/8), stdin);
    // Extract bits from byte buffer
    for(size_t i = 0; i < increase; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            bitbuf[*buf_size] = (buf[i] >> (7 - j)) & 1;
            (*buf_size)++;
        }
    }
    *bitbuf_read_head_ptr = bitbuf;
    return increase > 0;
}

int main(){
    printf("FILE:");
    bool bitbuf[BUF_SIZE*8];
    bool * bitbuf_read_head = bitbuf;
    size_t buf_size = 0; // In bits
    while(true){
        if(buf_size < 8){ // 8 bits, length of longest key
            if(!fill_buffer(bitbuf, &buf_size, &bitbuf_read_head)){
                // There may still be bits remaining (<8), encode the rest
                while(buf_size > 0){
                    for(int i = buf_size; i > 0; i--){
                        if(LUT[i] == NULL){
                            continue;
                        }
                        uint8_t key = 0;
                        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                            key |= bitbuf_read_head[j] << (i - j - 1);
                        }
                        if(LUT[i][key] != 0){
                            putchar(LUT[i][key]);
                            bitbuf_read_head += i;
                            buf_size -= i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        int max_key_size = (buf_size < 8) ? buf_size : 8;
        // Produce keys in descending order, check for first match, write to stdout, then move buffer head.
        // If there are no codewords of length n (that is, LUT[n] is NULL), then we skip to the next length.
        for(int i = max_key_size; i > 0; i--){
            if(LUT[i] == NULL){
                continue;
            }
            uint8_t key = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                key |= bitbuf_read_head[j] << (i - j - 1);
            }
            if(LUT[i][key] != 0){
                putchar(LUT[i][key]);
                bitbuf_read_head += i;
                buf_size -= i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "<EOF>\n");
    fflush(stderr);
    return 0;
}

js8file_enc.h
#include "ref.h"

// Indexed by codeword length (.bits)
const unsigned char * LUT[9] = {
    [0] = NULL,
    [1] = (unsigned char[0b10]){
        [0b0] = ' ',
        [0b1] = 'E'
    },
    [2] = NULL,
    [3] = NULL,
    [4] = (unsigned char[0b10000]){
        [0b1101] = 'T',
        [0b0011] = 'A'
    },
    [5] = (unsigned char[0b100000]){
        [0b11111] = 'O',
        [0b11100] = 'I',
        [0b10111] = 'N',
        [0b10100] = 'S',
        [0b00011] = 'H',
        [0b00000] = 'R'
    },
    [6] = (unsigned char[0b1000000]){
        [0b111011] = 'D',
        [0b110011] = 'L',
        [0b110001] = 'C',
        [0b101101] = 'U',
        [0b101011] = 'M',
        [0b001011] = 'W',
        [0b001001] = 'F',
        [0b000101] = 'G',
        [0b000011] = 'Y'
    },
    [7] = (unsigned char[0b10000000]){
        [0b1111011] = 'P',
        [0b1111001] = 'B',
        [0b1110100] = '.',
        [0b1100101] = 'V',
        [0b1100100] = 'K',
        [0b1100001] = '-',
        [0b1100000] = '+',
        [0b1011001] = '?',
        [0b1011000] = '!',
        [0b1010101] = '"',
        [0b1010100] = 'X',
        [0b0010101] = '0',
        [0b0010100] = 'J',
        [0b0010001] = '1',
        [0b0010000] = 'Q',
        [0b0001001] = '2',
        [0b0001000] = 'Z',
        [0b0000101] = '3',
        [0b0000100] = '5'
    },
    [8] = (unsigned char[0b100000000]){
        [0b11110101] = '4',
        [0b11110100] = '9',
        [0b11110001] = '8',
        [0b11110000] = '6',
        [0b11101011] = '7',
        [0b11101010] = '/'
    }
};

ref.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
// DEFAULT SETTING: 524288
// 512 KiB, packed (bytes read from stdin)
// 4 MiB, unpacked (512 KiB worth of bits stored in bitbuf)
// Changed for debugging purposes
#define BUF_SIZE 524288

typedef const struct codeword{
    const uint8_t key;
    const uint8_t bits;
} codeword;


EDIT: The first answer states that the default Windows stack size is 1 MB. I did not know this, and I'll test out this fix.

warning C4013: '__builtin_expect' undefined; assuming extern returning int - How did you even get it to link on Windows using cl.exe given that __builtin_expect doesn't exist on cl.exe (the Visual Studio tool chain)?

@selbie I realize that I put that in for Linux, not for Windows, since I was stuck on this problem. The problem occurs if you remove all hints, yet compiles. I'll update the question.

The code is quite cryptic. Please reduce it to [mcve].

This line in main():
bool bitbuf[BUF_SIZE * 8];

Where BUF_SIZE is defined in ref.h as 524288.  That's going to allocate 4 megabytes off the stack on startup.  That crashes your program before it can even get to the printf("FILE:") statement.
By default, the VC compiler only allows 1MB of stack size.
Solutions:

Change the above line to be:
bool* bitbuf = malloc(BUF_SIZE*8);
(Don't forget to free it when done)


OR

Use the compiler and linker flags for increasing stack size (I can look this up if you want), but the above solution of using a dynamic memory allocation is better.

Similarly, the char buf[BUF_SIZE]; in fill_buffer is taking up 512KB of stack.

Technically, the malloc() call should be: bool* bitbuf = malloc((BUF_SIZE*8) * sizeof(bool)); as sizeof(bool) is not guaranteed to be 1 byte: In C how much space does a bool (boolean) take up? Is it 1 bit, 1 byte or something else?

Note that most modern Unix-like systems provide 8 MiB of stack by default, which is why the Linux implementation works OK.
